# Vue : JWT Authorization header with Axios

Tags: vue.js, token

I created a front end application on vue.js and I use phoenix as backend. 
I try to make a request and returns an error : 
GET http://localhost:4000/api/v1/my_user 401 (Unauthorized)

it's better than having CORS issue.

In my script part, I build my header to manage access control and pass Authorization. At the end, I call my URL and pass variables.

```
getCurrentUser: function() {
  let axiosConfig = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("jwt")
    }
  };

  // call rest API
  axios
    .get("http://localhost:4000/api/v1/my_user", {}, axiosConfig)
    .then(res => {
      console.log("RESPONSE RECEIVED: ", res);
      //const jwt = res.data.jwt;
      //this.showComponent = false;
      console.log("res:" + res);
      //localStorage.setItem("jwt", jwt); // store the token in localstorage
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("AXIOS ERROR: ", err);
    });
},
```

localStorage.getItem("jwt") returns the correct token.
My issue is that i don't meet error by using postman client and when i pass as Authorization value the same values as in the header / Authorization

Comment: Could be one of many things. What headers are you receiving in your backend? Do you need to configure it to remove the Bearer text, are you trying to parse lowercase bearer and passing Bearer. Is token valid, has it got right authority etc.

Comment: Technically I receive a json containing the token value. This token is stored in localStorage. I tried with and without the "Bearer " part, I also parsed it but error remains the same. I tried to send the token back with postman and it works. I wonder if i put the Authorization where it should belong. I tried to put the token as second parameter between {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced this code by :

```
getCurrentUser: function() {
    axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] =
                "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("jwt");

   // call rest API
    axios
        .get("http://localhost:4000/api/v1/my_user")
        .then(res => {
         console.log("RESPONSE RECEIVED: ", res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("AXIOS ERROR: ", err);
    });
},
```